# How to remove the empty documents from the Document Term Matrix in R

Tags: r, data-analysis, text-processing, tm

I have got empty documents in my document term matrix. I need to remove them. This is code that I used to build the DocumentTermMatrix:

```
 tweets_dtm_tfidf <- DocumentTermMatrix(tweet_corpus, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf))
```

And this the warning Message that I am getting:

```
Warning message:
In weighting(x) :
  empty document(s): 823 3795 4265 7252 7295 7425 8240 8433 9303 12160 12278 14465 15166 15485 15933 20775 21666 21807 26131 27039 34035 34050 34101
```

I tried removing these empty documents using this code:

```
rowTotals <- apply(tweets_dtm_tfidf , 1, sum)
dtm_tfidf   <- tweets_dtm_tfidf[rowTotals> 0, ]
```

Here is the error that I am getting trying to remove them:

```
> rowTotals <- apply(tweets_dtm_tfidf , 1, sum)

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.8 Gb
```

Any idea on how to go about this? Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum in apply transforms your sparse matrix into a dense matrix and this eats up a lot of memory if it is a big sparse matrix.

And the `apply` function is not needed. There are functions for sparse matrices. Since the dtm is a `simple_triplet_matrix` you can use the row_sums from slam.

The following should work.

```
rowTotals <- slam::row_sums(tweets_dtm_tfidf)
dtm_tfidf <- dtm_tfidf[rowTotals > 0, ]
```

But remember anything you do to get your data out of sparse matrix might result in big memory hog object if you have a lot of words. You might want to use `removeSparseTerms` before moving on.

Comment: Just one more question I tried removing the sparse terms using the removeSparseTerms as you have mentioned. Here is my code: tweets_dtm_tfidf = removeSparseTerms(tweets_dtm_tfidf, 0.99)                  How do I determine the value? Like here I have used 0.99. I understand what that value stands for. Removes the values that doesn't appear more than a certain frequency of the number of times in all the documents combined. Just not sure how to determine the right value.?

Comment: You are welcome. And please accept answers on questions you asked. That helps in building your reputation.

Comment: Ah, the correct value is a bit of a guess. It depends on how many words you want to keep. The higher the number, the more words you keep. So 0.9 is everything that occurs 10% or more.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. Just accepted the answer. Didn't know about it. :)